# Sometimes ParseObject is null in the response

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception, null

I have parseObject "Event" with link to another parseObject "CustomUser"[image]

I make this request to get Custom user from Event by EventObjectID

```
eventID = "PRmB94GHrp";

ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", eventID);
parseQuery.include("author");
try {
    ParseObject eventParse = parseQuery.getFirst();
    eventParse.pin();
    eventParse.fetch();

    if (eventParse.getParseObject("author") != null) { //HERE IS SOMETIMES NULL
        customUserParseObject = eventParse.getParseObject("author"));
    }
```

In line **eventParse.getParseObject("author") != null**,  SOMETIMES IS NULL

How to solve it?

Comment: do you have option of optJSONObject..?

Comment: @PrashantMishra don't understand, what is it?

Comment: in place of get try opt if it works!

Comment: @PrashantMishra I don't work with Json, the question is about parse.com

Comment: Since you're fetching a specific object, is there a difference if you're using the preferred method to get an object by id? query.getInBackground(myId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {     (see top of doc for ParseQuery for more info)

Comment: @Handsomeguy thanks, removed .fetch() and .pin() - the bug is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
query.include("author");
query.getInBackground("PRmB94GHrp", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ParseObject authorObject = object.getParseObject("author"));
            //authorObject should contain the object
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't try executing it. Anyways i will try it and let you know